# Choppy video playback (Web browsing and in game)

Tags: gpu-driver

An odd video performance issue has come up.  I'm getting regular choppy video playback.  Kind of hard to explain but I'll do my best.

While doing any activity (like scrolling in a web browser, playing back video (gif/jif), gaming (Surviving Mars via Steam), VLC crashes, etc.) my screens will 'pause' for a tenth of a second like it is dropping frames and then resumes.  Repeats every second to two seconds.  The oddity is that the 2D/3D rendering when not 'hiccuping' is spot on and awesome.

This is a fresh install of a 16.04 and within a week to 18.04 soon after 18.04 came out.

I've already updated all my software (to the best of my knowledge), rebooted.  Running 4.15.0-20-generic.  What other pieces of information do you all need?

HW:

```
AMD Radeon 580
AMD Ryzen 1800x
ASRock AB350 Pro4
3x Acer G276HL
Samsung 960 Evo (/ via U.2 Ultra)
Samsung 850 Pro (mounted via SATA)
WD Black 4TB (mounted via SATA)
WD Green 2TB (mounted via USB3)
32 GB RAM
```

Update #1:

LSPCI:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 02)
03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 02)
03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b2 (rev 02)
1d:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
1d:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
1d:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
1d:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
1d:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
1d:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
1f:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
24:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
25:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/580] (rev e7)
26:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 580]
27:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
27:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
27:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller
28:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
28:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
28:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

LSMOD:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
pci_stub               16384  1
vboxpci                24576  0
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               471040  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
md4                    16384  0
nls_utf8               16384  1
cifs                  720896  2
ccm                    20480  0
fscache                61440  1 cifs
bnep                   20480  2
dm_crypt               36864  1
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_realtek   102400  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
edac_mce_amd           28672  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
btusb                  45056  0
ath9k                 151552  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
kvm_amd                86016  0
snd_hda_intel          40960  10
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
bluetooth             548864  33 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_amd
uvcvideo               86016  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
ath9k_hw              471040  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ath                    28672  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k,ath9k_common
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
pcbc                   16384  0
snd_usb_audio         196608  2
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
mac80211              778240  1 ath9k
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
videodev              184320  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_pcm                98304  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel           188416  3181
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
joydev                 24576  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
input_leds             16384  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cryptd                 24576  1593 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
snd                    81920  37 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
cfg80211              622592  4 mac80211,ath9k,ath,ath9k_common
ccp                    73728  0
k10temp                16384  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     32768  0
hid_logitech_dj        20480  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
hid_microsoft          16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  5 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp,hid_microsoft
amdkfd                180224  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
amdgpu               2703360  26
chash                  16384  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                   106496  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 amdgpu
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   401408  17 amdgpu,ttm,drm_kms_helper
r8169                  86016  0
i2c_piix4              24576  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
nvme                   32768  0
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
nvme_core              61440  4 nvme
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof
gpio_amdpt             16384  0
gpio_generic           20480  1 gpio_amdpt
```

Update #2:
So some  more random digging: glxgears returns an error upon exit:

```
321 frames in 5.0 seconds = 64.122 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.998 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.999 FPS
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 1051 requests (432 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

Related?

Comment: There was a question about AMD drivers recently, and it looks like the AMD proprietary drivers for 500 series cards are still in pre release. Have you tried installing the driver from here: https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux

Comment: also, it would likely help if you posted your lsmod and lspci output. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Configure the cad with amdconfig**

You may just need to do an initial configuration of your card after the upgrade:

```
sudo amdconfig –adapter=all –initial
```

**Try other drivers from "Software & Updates"**

Click on activities link in Dock ( grid of 9 dots ) and search for "updates". Launch Software & Updates click on additional drivers tab and look for other driver options there. Test drive other driver versions.

**Enable DRI3**

Add the following lines to /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMDGPU"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

**Install latest drivers**

There is an excellent tutorial for installing the latest drivers for AMD video cards:

[How to Install The Latest AMD Radeon Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Comment: So the PPA update went through but issues still happen.  Since the xorg.conf file doesn't exist on my system, do I need to have once created via 'xorg -configure'?

Comment: I would try to start running xorg -configure. This may even solve your problem. If not then add the entry to the xorg.conf file. You did and update/upgrade/reboot after adding the PPA, correct?

Comment: Yeah.  Did the update/upgrade/reboot stuff.  Looks like DRI3 is already enabled "xdpyinfo | grep DRI".  Guess I'm waiting for the new official drivers.

Comment: there is a pre release available for your card at the AMD website... did you try installing that?

Comment: Yeah.  I the install of the pre release AMD drivers had worse results.  Currently using what came with 18.04.

Comment: When I upgraded to 18.04 many of my settings were lost. Have you tried configuring your card with "sudo amdconfig –adapter=all –initial" to get it set up?

Comment: amdconfig doesn't exist on my system.